# how to pass selected value in a DropDownList as input parameter in @Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

i want to pass a parameter from dropdownlist to actionlink.

- DropDownList :
  @Html.DropDownList("Zpy_moisId", null, "")
- actionlink : 
  @Ajax.ActionLink("PRI", "_PRI",
          new AjaxOptions
          {
              HttpMethod = "GET",
              UpdateTargetId = "PRI",
              InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
          })

Thanks a lot

Comment: please add code block for insert code

Answer (score 0):

if have a select like this :

```
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

can pass selected value after select with jQuery $.ajax:

```
 $("select").change(function () {
        var data = $(this).find(":selected").text();
        $.ajax({
            url : "url/address" ,
            type: "GET",
            data : data,
            success : function () {
                alert("success done");
            }
        })
    });
```